# How to detect Google App Engine in library code to skip code that uses ManagementFactory or InitialContext

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jndi, jmx

We developming an open source library that's used on many platforms.

When it's used on Google App Engine (GAE), it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class.
Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

because we use the classes `ManagementFactory` and `InitialContext` to enable certain optional features. **How can we safely detect that we 're running on an environment (such as GAE) that doesn't support those classes?**

Note that we don't want to:

- depend on GAE specific classes in our compilation classpath, because our library needs to run on other platforms too (WildFly, JBoss EAP, OpenShift, Tomcat, ...)
- catch `NoClassDefFoundError`, because catching Errors is evil.

Comment: just make it configurable, two different realizations of an interface and give target developers a choice. gae developer will use an implementation w/o restricted classes

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Interesting idea, but that way it won't just run out of the box: depending on their environment, users need to configure it differently. That especially complicates things for end-users who want to build software that can run on multiple platforms. So this is not an option for us.

Comment: Maybe, but that's how it usually done. Through `interface` or concrete classes. And it's a standard de facto for Google libs, see all this `HttpTransport`, `JsonFactory` and so on, for different environments, etc

Answer (score 0):

We used this code to figure it out (yea, it does catch Error):

```
    try {
         Class.forName( "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" );
         jmxAvailable = true;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
         jmxAvailable = false;
    }
```